# css rem unit not working with font declarations

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, internet-explorer-10

This css property is not working on IE10:

```
font: bold 3rem/6rem Arial;
```

However, if I split this property to separate properties it works:

```
font-size: 3rem;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 6rem;
font-family: Arial;
```

I can also use PX instead and it also works:

```
font: bold 48px/96px Arial;
```

You can try it on every page with IE debugger. Why is this property not working on IE but on all other browsers?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The rem unit is not supported in IE for the font shorthand. It is a known bug. Hopefully this will be fixed. The only work-around I know is to specify the font-size again after the font property, or not use the shorthand when using rem.

The bug report is https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/772679/ie10-not-recognizing-font-decloration-when-rem-is-used-as-font-size-unit-of-measure

**Update:** note that this has been fixed as of IE11.

Comment: Besides, the `rem` unit is not supported at all by IE 8 and older, making its use rather questionable. It would sometimes be useful for convenience, helping you avoid calculating multipliers to use for `em`, but if you need to take old browsers into account, using `rem` you will end up with *more* trouble in styling, not less.